# How to do automation install package after sandbox created

Tags: apex, sandbox, schedulebatch, sandboxpostcopy

Im trying to do continues deployment everytime sandbox refresh.

But it was work fine if trigger via Developer Console (via personal account)
But there is nothing happen/run if trigger via Automation User Account in `SandboxPostCopy`
[image]
[image]
Here is my code

```
global class PackageInstallerSandboxPostCopy implements SandboxPostCopy {

    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        System.debug('Org ID: ' + context.organizationId());
        System.debug('Sandbox ID: ' + context.sandboxId());
        System.debug('Sandbox Name: ' + context.sandboxName());

        System.debug('Executing batch');
        Database.executeBatch(new PackageInstallerBatch());
    }
}
```

```
public class PackageInstallerBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug('PackageInstallerBatch.start');
        try {
            ManabieAllInOneVerion__c settings = ManabieAllInOneVerion__c.getInstance();
            String latestPackageVersion = settings != null ? settings.Version__c : '';
            
            if (latestPackageVersion == '') {
                latestPackageVersion = '04t5j000000uXwlAAE';
            }
            
            // TODO: Get password from secure custom setting
            String password = '';

            String instanceUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm(); // Get Salesforce instance URL dynamically
            String endpoint = instanceUrl + '/services/data/v59.0/tooling/sobjects/PackageInstallRequest';

            // Get current user's session ID (access token)
            String accessToken = UserInfo.getSessionId();

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            // Create the JSON payload
            String jsonPayload = '{' +
                '"SubscriberPackageVersionKey": "' + latestPackageVersion + '",' +
                '"NameConflictResolution": "Block",' + 
                '"SecurityType": "Full",' + 
                '"Password": "'+ password +'"' +
            '}';
            req.setBody(jsonPayload);

            System.debug('JSON payload: ' + jsonPayload); // For debugging purposes

            // Execute HTTP request
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

            // Handle response
            if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() <= 299) {
                // Successful request, handle response here
                System.debug('Package installation request successful: ' + res.getBody());

                String Id = res.getBody().substringAfter('"Id":"').substringBefore('"');
                System.debug('Id: ' + Id);
            } else {
                // Error handling for failed request
                System.debug('Package installation request failed. Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
                System.debug('Error message: ' + res.getBody());
                System.debug('Full response: ' + res);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Query with date returned
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Version__c, Name FROM ManabieAllInOneVerion__c'); 
    }
    
    // Execute method to process each batch of records
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<sObject> scope) {
        // Call the existing logic from PackageInstaller.installManabieAllInOnePackage method
        System.debug('PackageInstallerBatch.execute' + scope);
    }
    
    // Finish method to handle any post-processing logic
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // Perform any finishing tasks if needed
        System.debug('PackageInstallerBatch.finish');

    }
}
```

Comment: Automated User doesn't have a valid session ID (literally, it's `null`). There's no documented way to get a valid session ID.

Comment: So do we have anyway to workaround?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't one. I've never found a documented way to do this, nor even a hacky way. There's just too many restrictions on SandboxPostCopy/Automated User to make this happen.